# Inserting rows into table with only one column left and with out using column names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two identical tables A and B. Identical in the sense they both have same type of columns having the same name and data type.

A is having 100 columns and B is having 101 columns.

Only difference between them is B is having one extra column.

Now I am tryuing to insert the columns from A to B .

If both tables have same no of columns I can use the following insert statement.

```
 insert into B 
select * from A;
```

since both the tables having different number of columns i have to write all the columns names in the insert statements.

```
insert into B (col1,........col100)
select col1....col100 from A;
```

Now My question is .. is there any way we can write the statement in a simpler way like below so that time and no of lines in the code can be saved.

```
insert into B (exclude column 101)
    select * from A;
```

Comment: Are you able to create a view on table A so that it only includes the columns that are 'like' table B. Then you can select from view A into table B?

Comment: Yes. If insert is a regular activity then I have to go with view. But Objection creation should not increase just for inserts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

provided the last column of b is the column which differs from a columns, and both a and b columns are in the same order, and last column of b can be null:

```
 INSERT INTO b SELECT *,NULL FROM a;
```

If not, put any valid value instead of NULL.

Comment: Hi Thank you... This solves my problem . Is there any way we can insert if the order is not same?

Comment: If the order is not the same, I'm afraid you have to manually write all fields in the order you want, thus performing the permutation... I mean, for example, if a columns are arranged: `col1 col2 col3` and b columns are arranged: `col1 col3 col2 col4`, then you should do: `insert into b select col1,col3,col2,null from a`

Answer (score 1):

Since this is tagged sql-server, I'm guessing you're using SSMS to write your queries.. set your options correctly... see below image.

[image: ssms option screen]

Then switch to text output mode (CTRL-T)

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE 1=2
```

Copy and paste the csv column list from here... and mix and match the ordering of the columns as you deem necessary.

[image: column list as csv]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help: [How to construct a query that selects all columns except a certain one without specifying them?](http://www.sql-ex.com/help/select20.php)